# jQuery multiple forms in sidebar with same submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with some records in it and each of that records can be edited. I have a sidebar with edit form in it with the same inputs and the same submit button. When I try to execute the function on that button which will send an AJAX request, it executes as many times as many sidebars I opened before, when I need to update only that record which was actually edited.

That's the code:

```
    // On Edit
    $('.action-edit').on("click",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".add-new-data").addClass("show");
        $(".overlay-bg").addClass("show");

        const row = $(this).closest('td').parent('tr').first();
        const agendaID = row.data('agenda_id');
        const form = document.querySelector('#update_form');
        const url = $(form).data('action_url').replace('.ID.', agendaID);

        getAgendaInfo(agendaID);

        $('.add-data-btn').on('click', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
           
            console.log(agendaID); // displays IDs of all records where sidebar was opened. 

            const ajaxData = grabFormData();

            editAgenda(url, row, ajaxData);
        })

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are adding new `click` event listener each time you show a new editor but you don't remove the previous event listener.

Try doing `$('.add-data-btn').off()` before the `$('.add-data-btn').on('click'...`.

Comment: I don't like this solution. Calling .off() is a hacky way, because it clearly suggests that there are redundant steps in the event creation. It's way better to call ```$(someselector).on('click', '.action-edit', function(e) {/*...*/})``` instead exactly once. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that your click handler is created whenever that `.on()` function is evaluated. The issue is that you execute that multiple times. Instead of that, you will need to perform a few steps for an elegant solution:

## #1

Find a tag which exists before you populate your `action-edit` elements. In the worst case that would be `body` and I suggest that you need to start experimenting with

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on("click", '.action-edit',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".add-new-data").addClass("show");
        $(".overlay-bg").addClass("show");

        const row = $(this).closest('td').parent('tr').first();
        const agendaID = row.data('agenda_id');
        const form = document.querySelector('#update_form');
        const url = $(form).data('action_url').replace('.ID.', agendaID);

        getAgendaInfo(agendaID);

        $('.add-data-btn').on('click', function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
           
            console.log(agendaID); // displays IDs of all records where sidebar was opened. 

            const ajaxData = grabFormData();

            editAgenda(url, row, ajaxData);
        })

    });
});
```

Note that this needs to run **exactly** once and will automatically create `click` handlers for you.

## #2

Find the closest tag to your grid which already exists at the time the page is loaded and change the selector accordingly.

## #3

Test, test, test